# Boostrap 3 Collapse - Chaining icons based on collapse state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

firstly here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/6xpdeLa6/39/

The icons need to change based on the state of collapse/accordion, I want to keep a panel open always (user cannot close all the accordions) and have the necessary JS too. But the problem is when the default panel is open and user click's on it the accordion does not close but the icon changes. That has something to do with the initial js. I am not very through with javascript, any help would be appreciate.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="sub-menu-1 panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                    FASHION
                                </a>
                              </h4>
                            </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                              <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="list-normal sub-menu-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            Man
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            Women
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            Children
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                            Infants
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul><!-- /.sub-menu-list -->
                              </div>
                            </div><!-- /#collapseOne -->
                        </div><!-- /.panel -->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                                 SPORTS
                                </a>
                              </h4>
                            </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul class="list-normal sub-menu-list">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Sports Gear
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Sports Shoes
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Discounted Stuff
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Other Option
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Other Option 2
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                Other Option 3
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul><!-- /.sub-menu-list -->
                                </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
                            </div><!-- /#collapseTwo -->
                        </div><!-- /.panel -->
                    </div><!-- /.sub-menu-1 -->
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse:not(.in)").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse.in").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
    $('.panel-heading a').click(function(){ 
        $('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i").addClass("fa-plus").removeClass("fa-minus");
        $(this).parents('.panel-heading').find("i.fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        $(this).parents('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i.fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    });
});

// Keeps at least one collapse panel open
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your first section of code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse:not(.in)").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse.in").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");

    $('.panel-heading a').click(function(){ 
        if(!$(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
            $('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i").addClass("fa-plus").removeClass("fa-minus");
            $(this).parents('.panel-heading').find("i.fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
            $(this).parents('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i.fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        }
    });
});
```

The added if statement:

```
if(!$(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in'))
```

check if clicked panel already open or not and change the icon if it's not already open.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xpdeLa6/42/)**

Comment: I did vote up but it didn't allow me to select to as answer then, asked me to wait for 3 minutes, now I did.